# WooCommerce composite product plugin add to cart hook with quantity

Tags: woocommerce, product, composite

We are working with add to cart hooks a lot in WooCommerce so we are able to add products to our carts via our own plugins without messing around in the `functions.php` all too much.
But this time I think we came to our limits.

What we use is the [WooCommerce Composite Products](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/composite-products/) plugin and we have added multiple products into one composite product which ID is **`123`**.

By creating a link like this, we can add the composite product into our cart and select the components as we want:

[https://www.example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=123&wccp_component_selection[1593767685]=479&wccp_component_selection[1593767245]=289&wccp_component_selection[1593766620]=288&wccp_component_selection[1593436878]=284&wccp_component_selection[1593436879]=283](https://www.example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=123&wccp_component_selection%5B1593767685%5D=479&wccp_component_selection%5B1593767245%5D=289&wccp_component_selection%5B1593766620%5D=288&wccp_component_selection%5B1593436878%5D=284&wccp_component_selection%5B1593436879%5D=283)

The challenge now is that we want to add a different quantity for each component:

- component 1593767685 should be added 20 times
- component 1593767245 should be added 15 times
  etc

Working with the `quantity` attribute didn't get us far here because it would only add the whole composite product into the cart x-times but not each of the components:

[https://www.example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=123&wccp_component_selection[1593767685]=479&quantity=20..](https://www.example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=123&wccp_component_selection%5B1593767685%5D=479&quantity=20..).

So we're out of ideas now.
How can we add a composite product into the cart 1 time but control the quantity of each component as we want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dealing with the customer support of the plugin, the solution is simple as this:

https://www.example.com/cart/?wccps_c0=289&wccps_c1=288&wccpq_c0=34&wccpq_c1=67&quantity=1&wccpm0=1593767245&wccpm1=1593766620&wccpl=2&add-to-cart=448

is the right link.
while `wccps_cX` is the product ID and `wccpq_cX` is the quantity. `wccpmX` is the component ID and `wccpl=X` marks the number of components you want to add.